# Views 3, 2 different node types, filtered by the same contextual filter

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have two node types. Node A and Node B, both node types can have a reference to to a taxonomy term.

Now I am trying to construct a view which shows a list of both Node A and Node B, filtered by the taxonomy.

So Node A and Node B have different names for the the taxonomy field (field_nodea_taxonomy, field_nodeb_taxonomy). If add both of these fields as contextual filters and then try to filter on taxonomy term with id 10, by writing "10/10", i get only contents for the first filter.

How can i make it so to that it will show both content types, but filtered?

Comment: Do field_nodea_taxonomy and field_nodeb_taxonomy use the same taxonomy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If field_nodea_taxonomy and field_nodeb_taxonomy use the same taxonomy vocabulary, this problem can be addressed differently with a shared field.

I generally define a single shared field for each taxonomy vocabulary, and use it in every content type where it's needed (e.g., nodea and nodeb). If your requirements permit you to use this approach, your problem goes away, since a term filter on that single field will work for all content types.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering on two fields with the same value is not supported via UI. You have to code a [plugin](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_plugins/7) and/or [handler](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_handlers/7) to manage this use case.